# Character Constant Array is empty, even though values has been assigned to it [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character, constants

I am facing problems while assigning string value in a character constant array. Every time when it assigns string value to a particular position of character array. That position value in an array become initialized to empty string, after getting a new value in string variable. I have tried hard to get it out but in vain. Following is the code that I am using:

```
        const char *array[40];
        string line="";
        ifstream myfile( "text.txt");
        if (myfile) 
          {
            int in=0;
          while (getline( myfile, line ))  
            {

              array[in]=line.data();
                  in++;
           }
          myfile.close();
          }
        else return;
```

Now, array variable has all the empty string values. Please let me know how can I do it?

Comment: Think about what the pointers in the array point to (hint: you only have one string object. )

Comment: You probably want `std::vector<std::string> array;`.

Comment: You're in trouble if the file contains more than 40 lines.

Comment: *I have tried hard to get it out but in vain.* -- Then you want something [like this](http://ideone.com/6gCJuN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the internal data buffer of `string` object `line` and let `array[in]` point to it. When reading the next line, this buffer is either overwritten or may point to a different memory location, such that the previously written `array[in]` points to a memory that has been overwritten with new content or is invalid at all.

If you want to use a `const char*[...]` array, copy the buffer first:

```cpp
array[in]= strdup(line.c_str());
```

Note further, that `line.data()` gives you an array but without guarantee of a terminating 0x0 at the end. See documentation of `string::data()` at [cppreference.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/)

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, please don't forget to mark the question as accepted. Thanks!